# YAJSW remote debug the application

Tags: java, debugging, yajsw, tanuki

I have started java app with YAJSW but not able to remote debug , Have tried passing paramters in wrapper.app.additional as well as parameter but still not working when I pass from setenv then YAJSW starts in debug mode but not my applicaiton

```
wrapper.app.parameter.2 = -Xdebug
wrapper.app.parameter.3 = -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket\\,address=8888\\,server=y\\,suspend=n
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a solution

```
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Xdebug
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Xrunjdwp:"server=y\,transport=dt_socket\,address=127.0.0.1:8787\,suspend=y"
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with remote debugging using below parameters:
Just add line given below, at the bottom of the `catalina.bat` file in your tomcat.

```
CATALINA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

Just remove the "\\" from your parameter 3, I believe it should work.

Just make sure that `CATALINA_OPTS` is added to the path when `catalina.bat` file is being executed.

And if you are running any jar executable from bat file (on windows) just add below parameters to its classpath.

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n
```

Definitely, it should work.